# Yii2 uploadfile image from model method beforeSave

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model, yii2-validation

i try to upload 4 or less images, the ajax validation do not return any error, but on submit i get the follow:

> "errors": {
>   "imageFiles": [
>   "Please upload a file."
>   ]
>   }

attr:

```
/**
 * @var UploadedFile[]
 */
public $imageFiles;
```

Rules:

```
return [
        [['imageFiles'], 'required', 'on' => self::REPORT_STEP1],
        [['imageFiles'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => false, 'maxFiles' => 4],
];
```

BeforeSave:

```
public function beforeSave($insert)
{
    $files_urls = [];
    $this->imageFiles = UploadedFile::getInstances($this, 'imageFiles');

    foreach ($this->imageFiles as $file) {
        $path = Url::to(['/uploads/reports/'], true) . Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString() . '.' . $file->extension;
        $file->saveAs($path);
        $files_urls[] = $file->name;
    }

    $this->img_url = json_encode($files_urls);
    return parent::beforeSave($insert); // TODO: Change the autogenerated stub
}
```

Form:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
        'options' => [
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
        ]
    ]) ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'imageFiles[]')->fileInput(['multiple' => true, 'accept' => 'image/*']) ?>

    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton('Siguiente', ['class' => 'btn btn-standard']) ?>
    </div>

    <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Comment: Is it work when you disable AJAX validation?

Comment: no, it isn't work too